# Ampersand as a delim in a FOR /F statement

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, windows-scripting

I am trying to escape ampersand in a FOR /F statement in windows command line script, as follows:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=^&" %%A IN ("%Var%") DO (...
```

Result from running the script is still:

```
 & was unexpected at this time
```

What is the correct way to use & as a delimeter? Or should it be replaced with something else in the string to be parsed?

Comment: The error isn't produced by the code you showed. This test works `FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=^&" %%A IN ("123&456") Do echo %%A,%%B`. But `^&` defines the ampersand and the caret as delimeters

Comment: @jeb - It could very well be in the shown code, depending on the value of `%Var%`.

Comment: You should accept the answer that solved your issue.

Answer (score 5):

The ampersand is already escaped by double quotes. So more escaping is not necessary and successful:

```
@echo OFF &SETLOCAL
for /f "delims=&" %%i in (file) do echo %%i
```

Answer (score 2):

As Endoro has already stated, you don't need to escape the `&` within your delims specification.

Your error is probably occurring with the expansion of `"%Var%"`. If your value contains both quotes and `&` in such a way that the `&` is not quoted after expansion, then that is precicely the error you will get. Remember that the quotes in your statement can be canceled by quotes within the value.

You could probably solve the problem using delayed expansion

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=&" %%A IN ("!Var!") DO (...
```

But if your value also contains `!`, then you need to disable the delayed expansion before you you expand your FOR variables, otherwise the expanded values will be corrupted.

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=&" %%A IN ("!Var!") DO (
  endlocal
  ...
)
```